# Is $\dot{f}(0)$ a function or a point?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Say

\begin{align} 
g: & \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n
\\ \implies g': & \mathbb R^m \to \mathcal{L}(\mathbb R^m,\mathbb R^n)
\\ \implies g'(0): & \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n
\end{align}

and it's known that for some $v \in \mathbb R^m$ holds $g'(0)v=w \in \mathbb R^n$.

Let's define

\begin{align} 
f:  \mathbb R &\to \mathbb R^n
\\ t &\mapsto g(tv)
\end{align}

Then

\begin{align} 
\dot{f}(t) & = \frac{d}{dt}f(t)
\\ &=\frac{d}{dt}g(tv)
\\ &=g'(tv)v
\end{align}

Therefore

\begin{align} 
\dot{f}(0) & = g'(0v)v
\\ &=g'(0)v
\\ &=w
\end{align}

It's from my lecture notes where they just conclude that $\dot{f}(0)=\partial g(0)v=w$. The attempt of derivation is by me.

And the question is: isn't $\dot{f}(0) \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb R,\mathbb R^n)$? How is it compatible with $w\in\mathbb R^n$? What went wrong?

Comment: There's a natural isomorphism between $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R},V)$ and $V$ for every $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $V$ (namely $\lambda \mapsto \lambda(1)$). Viewing the natural isomorphism as an identity, the derivative of $f$ at $0$ "is" a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special notation $\dot{f}(t)$ might be defined to denote $f'(t)(1)$ and thus be an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Otherwise, it comes from a tacit identification of $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is common, since for every real vector space $V$ we have a *natural* isomorphism

$$\eta \colon \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R},V) \xrightarrow{\cong} V;\quad \eta(\lambda) = \lambda(1),$$

since such a $\lambda$ is of the form $\lambda(c) = c\cdot v$ for some $v\in V$.

When you have a natural isomorphism between two structures, it is often convenient to identify the two without mentioning the isomorphism.
From that viewpoint, $\dot{f}(t)$ "is" a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thank you! But it's still somewhat surprising for me. For example, $\mathbb R \cong \{(x,0) \in \mathbb R^2 \ | \ x \in \mathbb R \}$, so I feel like I started in the former and ended up in the latter, without understanding at which moment did it switch. And I thought that $\dot{f}$ is exactly $f'$ (so the dot simply indicates that it's w.r.t. time). Could you point out at what line of my post did the switch happen?